# Is it possible to know if my device can get my position

Tags: android, google-maps

Let's see, I'm working with Google Maps. I know Google uses a combination of technologies to get my position but sometimes it's impossible for Google to get it.

I've created a GoogleMap object and I set myLocationEnable to True. When Google can get my position, there's no problem, when I press the button it brings my to my position but sometimes, when I press the button it does nothing. I guess this happens when my position is unreachable for Google.

So my question is, is there a method which let me know when my position is unreacheable? I would like to advise the user he must turn on GPS, something like this:

```
public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
    if (myPositionUnreachable){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turn on GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Can anybody give me a hint? I would appreciate it. Thanxs a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if GPS is enabled like this:

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean gpsEnabled = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

You can register a listener that will inform you about GPS changes.

```
// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the GPS location provider.
      makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        switch (status) {
            case LocationListener.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
            case LocationListener.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                //TODO do what you need here
                break;
            case LocationListener.AVAILABLE:
                //it's working again
                break;
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

To efficiently setup updates read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestPerformance)

**Update**

If you like you can also use [Location API](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) from Google Service and register the same listener through that API.

**Update 2**

To immediately get position you can call

```
Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Description from javadoc:

> Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location
>   fix obtained from the given provider.
>
> This can be done without starting the provider. Note that this
>   location could be out-of-date, for example if the device was turned
>   off and moved to another location.
>
> If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.

Comment: I know, but sometimes it's not necessary that GPS is enable to get the position

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope it's sufficient for you now.

Comment: Thanxs a lot for your help but I think I didn't expalin well what I wanted to achiev. I would first like to try getting user position without telling him to enable GPS, so if I can't get the position, I would tell him to enable it.

Comment: Thaxs a lot for your help